# VBA Ribbon getPressed for a toggleButton

Tags: vba, ribbon

I am trying to set the value of a toggleButton. This is my Ribbon XML

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
 <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
  <tabs>
   <tab id="customTab" label="CC">
    <group id="grpSegments" label="Segments">
     <dropDown id="cbLeaves" label="Segments" onAction="LeavesChanged" getSelectedItemID="GetCBLeavesSelectedID">
      <item id='item4' label='4'/>
      <item id='item6' label='6'/>
      <item id='item8' label='8'/>
      <item id='item12' label='12'/>
     </dropDown>
     <button id="cGenerate" label="Generate" size="large" onAction="ArrangeRosette"/>
    </group>
    <group id="grpGuides" label="Guides">
     <toggleButton id="cToggleGuide" label="Show Guides" onAction="GuideToggled" getPressed="GetGuideState"/>
    </group>
   </tab>
  </tabs>
 </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I have a method with the signature

```
Sub GuideToggled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef Pressed As Boolean)
```

However, this always results in an error about macro not being accessible.

whereas, the getSelectedItemID for the dropDown has no trouble

```
Sub GetCBLeavesSelectedID(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef ItemID As Variant)
```

I cannot find any resource which has the getPressed callback documented.

Comment: Have you looked here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd910802(v=office.12).aspx ?

Comment: Thanks. I had looked at that - infact, the downloaded book. It does not have the callbacks. Olle's answer below has a useful suggestion of using the Ribbon XML editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reference `GuideToggled` and `GetGuideState` in your ribbon XML, so you need them both:

```
'Callback for cToggleGuide onAction
Sub GuideToggled(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)
End Sub

'Callback for cToggleGuide getPressed
Sub GetGuideState(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
End Sub
```

Have you tried the [custom UI editor tool](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2006/05/26/customuieditor.aspx)? It will help you find the right signatures for your VBA callbacks.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that the custom UI editor also did the callbacks - neat!
I had converted the signature from the VSTO code. Turns out the data type needed to be `Variant` and not `Boolean`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Callback for HighlightTBtn onAction
Sub GoTo_onAction(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)
MsgBox pressed
If pressed Then
MsgBox "Button On"
Else
MsgBox "Button Off"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation.